# React weird implicit mutation of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have TaskManager component in which I have state

```
const [sections, setSections] = useState({
sectionArr: [/*some stuff*/],
taskArr: [/*some stuff*/],
})
```

and a bunch of `conlole.log`s

```
  console.log("Sections is", sections);
  console.log("Type: ", typeof sections);
```

Also I have AddSectionButton which is basically a button that adds new sections.
It's onClick callback function is

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    const newObject = {
      name: "added section",
      id:
        // random id
        Math.floor(Math.random() * (Number.MAX_VALUE - 0)) + 0,
      position: 0,
    };
    const sectionsCopy = sections;
    const updatedState = sectionsCopy.sectionArr.push(newObject);

    setSections(updatedState);
  };
```

When I run my application at first everything is ok, `my console.log`s output is correct

```
Sections is {sectionArr: Array(3), taskArr: Array(3)}
Type:  object
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
ƒ map() { [native code] }
```

But then when I click my AddSectionButton - output gets really weird

```
Sections is 4
Type:  number
```

I no way changed my whole state with 4.
Any ideas about why my state changes?

Comment: If you console.log the `updatedState` before you run `setSections(updatedState);` what does it show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rray#push method works in situ, you don't have to assign it to a new variable. It won't return a new array, but will modify the original one and will return it's length. That's why you are getting a number as the result.

I would do something like this instead of using push

```
updateState = { sectionArr: [...sectionsCopy.sectionArr, newObject], taskArr: [...sectionsCopy.taskArr] }
```

Or even maybe using the sectionsCopy variable to pass to the setSections because using push would mutate that variable and return the number.